# Perfect square method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I didn't get this method.
\begin{equation*}
3a^2-9a+6=3(a^2-3a+2) \\
=3(a^2-1a*3+3^2-3^2+2)= \\
= 3[(a-3)^2-7],
\end{equation*}
then?

Comment: Yes, then what? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: By the way, the last equality is wrong. $(a-3)^2=a^2-6a+9$, not $a^2-3a+9$.

Comment: @Hans to continue... The answer is 3(a-2)(a-1) but how to get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, so you want to factor the polynomial. Here's how:

$$3(a^2-2 \frac{3}{2} a + 2) = 3\left(\left(a-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{9}{4} + 2\right) = 3\left(z^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right)$$
$$= 3\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 3(a-2)(a-1),$$
where I temporarily used the substitution $z=a-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: And of course, when you are done you should multiply out $3(a-2)(a-1)$ to check that you really get back to the polynomial that you started with! (Just to verify that you haven't made any errors during the calculation.)

Answer (score 7):

There is also a simple way that involves no fraction calculation,it goes like this :

$ 3a^{2}-9a+6 $

$  = 3a^{2}-6a-3a+6 $

$  = a(3a-6)-(3a-6) $

$  = (3a-6)(a-1) $

$  = 3(a-1)(a-2) $

Comment: Simple once you know the answer. ;)  Not much of a general method, however.

Comment: I disagree,this is how I was taught to factorize a quadratic equation in school :)

Comment: So how would you do $3a^2-9a+5$?

Answer (score 1):

You can guess and then confirm that $a=1$ is a zero of $3a^{2}-9a+6$. Thus
you can factor it as

$3a^{2}-9a+6=3(a-1)(a-x)=3x-3a-3ax+3a^{2}$

and solve for $x$. Comparing the coefficients of $a^{2},a,a^{0}$, you get

$3=3,3x=6,-3-3x=-9$,

which is equivalent to $x=2$ and $1+x=3$. Hence $x=2$ and

$3a^{2}-9a+6=3(a-1)(a-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire to factor it by way of completing the square then it is simpler to first multiply by 4, namely

$$\rm\ \ 4\:(a^2-3\: a+2)\ =\ (2\:a-3)^2 - 1\ =\ (2\:a-2)\:(2\:a-4)$$

Finally, divide both sides through by $\rm\ \: 4\ =\ 2\cdot 2$